# How do you get a drawable from a StateListDrawable for a specific state?

Tags: android, robotium, statelistdrawable

I need to get the pressed state drawable of the StateListDrawable of a button.

I get the StateListDrawable like this:

`StateListDrawable drawable = button.getBackground();`

But I can't find anything useful in the internet on the next step I would take.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get specific drawable from state list drawable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26713618/get-specific-drawable-from-state-list-drawable)