# Get specific drawable from state list drawable

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable, android-input-method, statelistdrawable

I have a state list drawable, and i want to get a specific drawable from the state list drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:kplus="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


    <item kplus:key_type_space_alt="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/space_1_pressed" />
    <item kplus:key_type_space_alt="true" android:drawable="@drawable/space_1_normal" />

    <!-- TopNav keys. -->

    <item kplus:key_type_topnav="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_down" />
    <item kplus:key_type_topnav="true" android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_down" />
    <item kplus:key_type_topnav="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_normal" />

    <!-- TopRow keys. -->

    <item kplus:key_type_toprow="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/numeric_presseed" />
    <item kplus:key_type_toprow="true" android:drawable="@drawable/numeric_normal" />
</selector>
```

I select the correct drawable state for each key, something like this:

```
if (keyIsNumbers) {
    if (KPlusInputMethodService.sNumbersState == 2) {
        drawableState = mDrawableStatesProvider.KEY_STATE_TOPNAV_CHECKED;
    }
}
```

Now the states are defined like this:

```
KEY_STATE_TOPNAV_NORMAL = new int[] {keyTypeTopNavAttrId};
KEY_STATE_TOPNAV_PRESSED = new int[] {keyTypeTopNavAttrId, android.R.attr.state_pressed};
KEY_STATE_TOPNAV_CHECKED = new int[] {keyTypeTopNavAttrId, android.R.attr.state_selected};
```

Now my question is how to extract the correct drawable for each state ? I need to get the 9patch padding of the drawable, because if the state have different padding on 9patch it will get the padding only for the top drawable, and i want to set the padding manually for each key (drawable.getPadding(rect)).

Comment: you cannot get the Drawables that form StateListDrawable

Comment: i was thinking i could get them using the attribute id from stateDrawable[0] u sure its not possible ?:(

Comment: what do you need id for? also i dont understand why do you need to access the particular Drawable...

Comment: i resolved it using ben75 solution, works fine, but i will keep it under supervision to see if something changes.

Comment: This answer can help and doesn't use no public Api: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25038966/8716371

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**Obsolete answer.
Please check answer from VinceStyling for a better solution with SDK 29+**

---

There is [no public API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable.html) to get the drawable from the state.

There are some methods in [`StateListDrawable`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4_r1/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable.java) but they are `@hide` with the comment *"pending API council"*.

You can invoke them by reflection... but it's **at your own risk !!!**. (it may change in future releases)

Those methods are :

- [getStateDrawableIndex](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4_r1/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable.java#StateListDrawable.getStateDrawableIndex%28int%5B%5D%29)
- [getStateDrawable](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4_r1/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable.java#StateListDrawable.getStateDrawable%28int%29)

Here is how to proceed (exceptions omitted) :

```
int[] currentState = view.getDrawableState();
StateListDrawable stateListDrawable = (StateListDrawable)view.getBackground();
Method getStateDrawableIndex = StateListDrawable.class.getMethod("getStateDrawableIndex", int[].class);
Method getStateDrawable = StateListDrawable.class.getMethod("getStateDrawable", int.class);
int index = (int) getStateDrawableIndex.invoke(stateListDrawable,currentState);
Drawable drawable = (Drawable) getStateDrawable.invoke(stateListDrawable,index);
```

Comment: works like a charm for now. I will keep this under supervision to see if it will change in the future.

Comment: Thanks man you are genius !! I can give you 100 points for these answer if possible

Comment: Just a heads up, this won't work in Android P, https://developer.android.com/preview/restrictions-non-sdk-interfaces.html

Comment: The API is finally being made public in Android Q

Comment: Works pretty well! It is a bit worrying using a non-public API though.

A small suggestion for the reflection calls is to use `getDeclaredMethod(...)` instead of just `getMethod(...)`. This can throw a NoSuchMethodException (not sure if this is a side-effect of the @hide thing)

Comment: @AniFichadia `getDeclaredMethod(...)` also throws a `NoSuchMethodException`

Comment: It's not working and now it throws NoSuchMethodException, can you tell me the alternative?

Comment: @MuhammadNatiq I would suggest to build a new solution based on this method added in API 29 : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable#findStateDrawableIndex(int[])  ... or check answer from VinceStyling  (it looks more up-to-date than this one)

Answer (score 1):

now it is the way to get specific drawable without reflection:

```
StateListDrawable pressedDrawable = (StateListDrawable) this.mPressed;
final int state = android.R.attr.state_pressed;
final int index = pressedDrawable.findStateDrawableIndex(new int[]{state});
if (index >= 0) {
    Drawable drawable = pressedDrawable.getStateDrawable(index);
    if (drawable instanceof GradientDrawable) {
        ((GradientDrawable) drawable).setCornerRadius(mRoundConerRadius);
    }
}
```